# Google App Engine: BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol GROUP

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gql

I have a Google App Engine datastore NDB model

```
class Track(ndb.Model):
    datetime = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    artist = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
```

and I wish to group matching tracks by title and artist that are played at different datetimes using the `GROUP BY` [GQL clause](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#clauses). I am not sure why this GQL query isn't working:

```
qry = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Track GROUP BY title, artist")
```

which returns the error `BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol GROUP` while the following works fine

```
qry = ndb.gql("SELECT DISTINCT title, artist FROM Track")
```

The `BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol X` error also occurs when I place some arbitrary clause `X` into the query, suggesting that GQL doesn't support the `GROUP BY` GQL clause (like older answers here suggest) even though it exists in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#clauses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not supported in GQL by App Engine Datastore, so you will have to do order by and then post filter in your app.

The documentation you link is for v1beta2 for Google Cloud Datastore (the standalone version). For App Engine Datastore, [read here instead for GQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference)

Comment: PS: I'll look into making the GCD docs clearer on this point.